# Can i use both SASS an LESS in Vue js

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs2, less

I have started a project with Vue js in combination with [Buefy](https://buefy.github.io/#/). Buefy (Bulma) is developed in SASS and i work with LESS. I want to override some values from Buefy but my project is setup with LESS. My question is:

Can i work with both preprocessors?

In my components i use:

`<style lang="less"></style>`

but i also want to be able to use:

`<style lang="sass"></style>`

Can this be done?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Sure, you can"

> However, I discourage you to do so, because you're going to preprocess the styles twice, with different preprocessors (scopes, class naming, unexpected weird errors), you'll have to debug your code to see if it's working right.

**Moving forward:** depending on your Vue setup, the configuration you need for the webpack(in case you use it, but gulp, grunt, etc... work too ) you have.

In case of webpack just add the configuration for Sass in your `{projectRoot}/webpack.config.js`, inside `module` `rules` array under .vue rule:

```
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue'
  }, 
  // CODE GOES HERE =====>
  {
      test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
      loader: 'style!css!sass'
  }
```

And in your `vue` option in the same file (create if you don't have one, should be under `module` option):

```
vue: {
    loaders: {
      scss: 'style!css!sass'
    }
  }
```

---

You have to install `node-sass` and `css-loader` and `sass-loader` and `style-loader`...

```
$ npm install --save-dev node-sass css-loader sass-loader style-loader
```